# Bench power selection

Tags: power-supply, power

I am trying to simulate a behaviour of a battery voltage line in my system. The system or DUT is as shown below. The battery is a 24 V battery. It is connected to the load (MCUs, LEDs,...etc) and a motor inductive load as well. So, normally the 24 V is a smooth DC level. But, when the motor kicks in we see the rail going as low as 10-11 V. Sometimes even less.

[image]

We have a capacitor bank that can resolve this to a very large extent. Now, that has been included and has resolved the problem. My load does not reset due to this crazy dip.The below image shows the dip from 24 to 10 V or so. This is observed for about 70 ms.

[image]

Now, the challenge is that the motors differ from unit to unit. So, say it is model A, the motors will differ from vehicle to vehicle. So, the dip and the duration will differ. To protect the load I have a capacitor bank but, with each different vehicle I might need additional/reduced capacitors.

I would like to test my circuitry using some bench power supply that can simulate the power input showing some capacitive decay and rise. Do we have such programmable bench power supplies that can show such a behaviour?

Comment: Not an answer to the equipment sourcing question, but if you have not already you might wish to isolate the important parts of your circuit and the added capacitors from the battery with a diode, which might greatly reduce the required capacitance. That way the voltage can dip for some time but the capacitors keep the MCU etc. from resetting. '

Comment: What are the cable sizes? Are you seeing large losses when the motor starts? What is the capacity of the battery for supplying high current demand like motors? Deep cycle batteries behave differently to batteries used to start large car and truck engines.

Comment: looks like an inline resistor with a cap across it. play optician to find suitable values.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany - we already isolated it. And this dip is at the input of the isolated dc-dc supply. I checked with Tektronix, Keysight for such power supplies, that can me made to behave like an analogue power rail as shown in the diagram. But, no luck.

Comment: @SolarMike - My system is connected to the battery via 16AWG wires (2 pairs, 2 - Vcc and 2 - GND).

Comment: ++ to Spehro Pefhany. If you have an idea of the current drawn from the system it is easy to compute the necessary capacitance you need. And of course: Battery=>diode=>capacitor=>MCU. You should easily solve your issue.

Comment: @robotsmith - my doubt is not in computing the capacitance. Though, the end result would be modifying the capacitor bank. My ask is are there any power supplies (table top/bench) which can be programmed to give voltage in this manner. With this, I can test my circuitry and see how it will behave.